# Replacing a content in HyperLink with Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I am trying to replace a content in NavigateUrl with Eval Content.

My aspx code is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RNum") %>'  NavigateUrl='<%# AreaID == "249" ? "http://google.com" : "http://someadress/login.main?req={0}" %>' />                
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="border_right" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here, I want to replace `{0} inside a NavigateUrl` with the `<%# Eval("RNum") %>` value.

I tried replacing it but it didnt worked.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where are you formating or doing the concatenation, but this should do the job:

```
<asp:HyperLink  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RNum") %>'  
NavigateUrl='<%# AreaID == "249" ? 
             "http://google.com" : 
             "http://someadress/login.main?req=" + Eval("RNum") %>' />
```